# Conversion from string to type Integer is not valid

Tags: vb.net

I have the below code in my app... Nothing is declared as a integer so I dont understand or see where the problem could be... It is saying:

Conversion from string "9838 Co Rd 47" to type 'Integer' is not valid.

The address is flowing through the entire function as a string the only place I think it could be getting changed somehow is in a function call... Below is the function that throws the exception. Followed by the function that returns the *address*... The error comes from the 
_holder = item.bill_to.remove(*address*) line

```
  For Each item In _QuickImport
            Dim BusinessName As String = Nothing
            Dim CustomerName As String = " "
            _Id = item.id
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Customer) Then
                Dim _holder As String = String.Empty
                Dim _contact_ As String = item.Contact
                Dim _address_ As String = String.Empty

                If item.Bill_to.Contains(_contact_) Then
                    _holder = item.Bill_to.Replace(_contact_, " ")
                End If
                If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(_holder) Then
                    If item.Bill_to.Contains("Co Rd") Then
                        _address_ = ExtractAddressWithCoRd(_holder)
                    End If
                Else
                    If item.Bill_to.Contains("Co Rd") Then
                        _address_ = ExtractAddressWithCoRd(item.Bill_to)
                    End If
                End If

                If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.Customer) Then
                    If item.Customer.Contains(":") Then
                        BusinessName = item.Customer.Split(":")(0)
                        CustomerName = item.Customer.Split(":")(1)
                    Else
                        CustomerName = item.Customer
                    End If
                End If


                If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(BusinessName) Then
                    If item.Bill_to.Contains(BusinessName) Then
                        _holder = item.Bill_to.Replace(BusinessName, " ")
                    End If
                End If



                Dim _Id_ As Integer = _Id

                If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_holder) Then
                    Dim _check As Boolean = True
                    _check = ValidZip(_holder)
                    If _check = True Then
                        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(_address_) Then
                            _holder = Convert.ToString(_holder)
                            _address_ = Convert.ToString(_address_)
                            _holder = item.Bill_to.Remove(_address_)
                        End If
                        parseAddress(_holder, _Id)
```

The other function is:

```
    Private Function ExtractAddressWithCoRd(ByVal input As String) As String
        Dim add1 As String = String.Empty
        Dim add2 As String = String.Empty
        Dim parts() As String = input.Split(" "c)
        For i As Integer = 0 To parts.Length - 1
            If parts(i) = "Co" AndAlso i > 0 Then
                add1 = parts(i - 1)
            ElseIf parts(i) = "Rd" AndAlso i < parts.Length - 1 Then
                add2 = parts(i + 1)
            End If
        Next

        Return add1 + " Co Rd " + add2
    End Function
```

This is where I think something is getting changed to a integer value... but this is all declared as string as well...

Any ideas????

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> This is where I think something is getting changed to a integer
>   value...

No, that's not it. Read the error message again:

> Conversion from string "9838 Co Rd 47" to type 'Integer' is not valid.

"Conversion from string" means that your `_address_` variable really IS a string, and it's value is even displayed ("9838 Co Rd 47").

It tries to convert this string to an integer because `item.Bill_to` is a `String` and `String.Remove` expects an integer argument (the position from which to remove characters), but you pass a string instead. What you're looking for is `String.Replace`, which you already use elsewhere:

```
_holder = item.Bill_to.Replace(_address_, "")
```

Comment: Good stuff... I thought that might be what it was but it thought I had used remove somewhere else like that.... Thanks much for the help...

Answer (score 0):

Are you using options strict? Perhaps in your return you should use

```
Return add1 & " Co Rd " & add2
```

Since add1 appears to be 9838?